# Jenkins Active Choices Cascading Choice for 3 Parameters Not Working

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins job with 3 parameters (Environment, Branch, Version) Using the Active Choices plugin. If Developers are deploying to Prod - I don't want them to be able to push a build from trunk. At present the dependency of params looks like this **Environment -> Branch -> Version**.

When the pages loads it displays **DEV** by default, which allows deployment from trunk or release and whatever artifacts have been built for the selection, however when I change the Environment to **PROD** - I would expect Branch to refresh to only show **release** (which it does), but Version does not update and continues to show artifacts from **trunk**.

**Environment Param**

```
return[
'DEV:selected',
'QA',
'BIZ',
'DEMO',
'PROD'
]
```

**Branch Param**(The Try/Catch is the only way I could get it to display on first load)

```
try{
    switch(Environment){
        case~/.*PROD.*/:
            return ['release']
            break
    default:
        return ['trunk','release']
        break
    }
} catch (all) {
    return ['trunk','release']
}
```

**Version Param**

```
def content = newURL("https://{{MyArtifactsUri}}/$Branch/").text
assert content, "Empty."
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(content)
return json.name.reverse()
```

Answer (score 0):

The Version should be defined as an Active Choices Reactive Parameter (Single Select).

As I understand from your question, Version is dependant on the value of Environment and Branch.

You will need to write some groovy script (or use a predefined Scriptler script) that takes the values of Environment and Branch and returns the appropriate (filtered?) list of available Versions for the user to select.

Comment: The options I have for "Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter" is
`- Input text box
- Numbered list
- Bullet items list
- Formatted HTML
- Formatted hidden HTML`

The URI needs to be reevaluated for each branch.

Comment: Correct, I meant Reactive Parameter.  Corrected above.

Comment: That's the type I'm already using. It seems like this works fine between two parameters, but not if you have it reacting to a parameter, which is itself reacting to another parameter. I've also tried adding **Branch** and **Environment** to the Referenced parameters for the **Version** parameter.